# IIS .NET Authorization Rules or MVC Route rules?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing, rules

I want to restrict access to a folder, not a page, so I thought the best approach would be using the IIS Remote Manager and add a .NET Authorization Rules entry to deny All Users to the folder in question.

The next step is to add authorization for Users who may be in a certain role (I'm guessing this applies to Users logged into an MVC Site, but I don't know yet).

In testing the first step what I discovered was the MVC 3 Application directs the visitor to a logon page.

The first challenge I ran into, still looking to resolve.

The original subdomain format:

```
subdomain1.site.com
```

The locked down folder is "images", but the path to the locked down folder:

```
subdomain1.site.com/content/images
```

When you try to access an image in the locked down folder, you get redirected to:

```
subdomain1.site.com/subdomain1/Account/LogOn...
```

I would expect this to be:

```
subdomain1.site.com/Account/LogOn...
```

I have another question posted regarding [URL Rewrite...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854705/iis-7-url-rewrite-config-issue-or-mvc-route) here on StackOverFlow, not sure what the correct solution should be so I separated these questions.

I know you can restricted a page based on logged in Users and Roles, but that only applies to the page and not files that may exist in a folder.

My thought on this is to deny all access to the folder and then add in rules for authorized roles.  If Security works the way I think it does then when a User logs into the MVC 3 Site, they will have credentials with the assigned Roles.

In this capacity, it should then allow them to access any restricted files in the locked down folder as long as the same Roles are mapped in the rules.

Comment: I'm not clearly understand your question but this post(http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/authorizing_folders_using_routeexistingfiles) may help you. It describes how to prevent access to folders using the RouteExistingFiles property. Note that in ASP.NET MVC 4 then RouteExistingFiles property is available are route level and not at global level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP MVC Authorize all actions except a few](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780436/asp-mvc-authorize-all-actions-except-a-few)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  It's actually something unique, as far as I can, that I couldn't find any solution to after scouring the internet for about a week.

Comment: I did some testing on the method linked by Mark, but I still ended up with the same results.  Whenever you try to access a file in a folder that you're trying to secure, if the user or visitor doesn't have access then the MCV Application directs the User to a LogOn page.  The only problem is on the redirect you end up at the fully qualified path to the master domain + sub-folder + sub-domain instead of sub-domain.master-domain.com/area.  I narrowed it down to what I believe to be an IIS config setting, I had to create an Outgoing rule to rewrite the path.  The URL Rewrite link has more info.

Comment: While you can control page content, if you have the full path to a file that is linked on a page then you can totally bypass any security you might have in place for viewing the page with the link.  I didn't want files to be downloaded without authorization.  I used images as a sandbox but they were ultimately replaced by other file types.  I ended up using part of what Mark linked, creating an IIS Outbound rule on the locked down folder and used Controller.File(...) on an ActionResult for sending files once authorization was established.